# How to expand light from fibre optics?

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy, fiber-optics

I am building a spectrophotometer for my robotics science club. I am using fibre optics cable to transport emission signal from the sample to spectrometer,next it is projected on the refelctive diffraction grating and then on the camera. However I discovered that the spectrum thanks to fibre optics is super thin (what a surprise) and I can't catch it one the camera. I considered a "beam expander" made of to colaminating lenses of different focal distances, however in professional specrophotmeter there is just a slit. Does it expand the light simply by diffraction? Is my method worth considering? I attach the image of current design. What camera would you recommend for detection?

[image]

Comment: There was a good link for a moment. It seems to have been erased. [Using optical fibers in astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/49054). In general, a good place to go when you have questions about optical components is [The RP Photonics Encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html)

Comment: Cheap diffraction spectrographs made of pieces sliced off a compact disc mounted in a cardboard housing will suffice. Instructions for how to build them are on the Interwebs and this is a fun project for students to do. You can also find diffraction gratings that attach to a cell phone; running an app on the phone will turn the phone into a very cool spectrometer which allows you to share spectra by messaging!

Comment: Guys, I know. I have done quite big research on spectrometers, and the one made of disc and shoe is unacceptable. The one I am desgining usesprofessional blazed diffraction grating. From the construction of our rover it has to have fibre optics to transfer the signal

Comment: And the only issue is how to expand the beam coming out of the fibreooptics, not the spectrometer in general

Comment: The blazed diffraction grating has 1200 groves/mm, dimensions 12×12×6, blaze angle 17° 27'.

Comment: For fibre optics it uses FC connectors and the seller descirbes it as "type 9/125 micro meters". It is singlemode

Comment: I have a fiberoptics with FC connector already. So you suggest to use "thicker" FO with sth like this: https://animalab.pl/kolimator-swiatlowodowy. Sorry for polish